# Flutter : List<Document>, how to remove duplicate documents according to its title

Tags: list, flutter, arraylist, duplicates

Let's say I have a class Document like this :

```
class Document {

  String text;
  String title;
  String date;

}
```

I created a List of Document (List Document  listDocs), and I would like to delete documents that have the same title, and keep ONLY the one with the earliest date.

For example if I have 3 documents with same title (but different texts and dates), I want to keep only the document with the earliest date.

Is there an easy way ?

thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort the list of objects by its date, you can do `MyDocumentList.sort((a, b) => a.date.compareTo(b.date));`

To make sure there is no second object with the same title you can use a `Set.` which is

`A collection of objects in which each object can occur only once.`

In this set you would store all the seen titles. Then you would go over `MyDocumentList`, try to store its title and only add a new `Document` to `uniqueDocuments`, if `seenDocumentTitles` does not contain the title of the current `Document` (if `seenDocumentTitles.add` returns true, meaning the set didn't contain the documents title)

```
Set<String> seenDocumentTitles = Set<String>();
List<Document> uniqueDocuments = MyDocumentList.where((document) => seenDocumentTitles.add(document.title)).toList();
```

For an example check this out:
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/20a889b174d2e45f7255d1b110be0627

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function that returns an earlier date time object from two given dates like so:

```
DateTime longer(String dateString, String dateString2) {
  DateTime dateTime = DateFormat("yyyy-MMMM-dd").parse(dateString);
  DateTime dateTime2 = DateFormat("yyyy-MMMM-dd").parse(dateString2);

  return dateTime.isBefore(dateTime2) ? dateTime : dateTime2;
}
```

Then, to check which date amongst the three is earlier, you add a method to your class like:

```
DateTime longest(String dateTime, String dateTime2) {
DateTime thisDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MMMM-dd").parse(this.date);
  return thisDate.isBefore(longer(dateTime, dateTime2)) ? thisDate : longer(dateTime, dateTime2);
}
```

If you want to decouple that method from your `Document` class you can do so:

```
DateTime longest(String dateTime, String dateTime2, String dateTime3) {
DateTime firstDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MMMM-dd").parse(dateTime);

  return firstDate.isBefore(longer(dateTime2, dateTime3)) ? firstDate : longer(dateTime2, dateTime3);
}
```